# Javascript time precision

Tags: javascript, datetime-format

Can anyone advise what type of precision is this time stamp?

```
<Timestamp>2022-03-23T10:34:56.8079862Z</Timestamp>
```

I can use

```
new Date().toISOString();
```

which generates this

> 2022-09-04T22:09:25.416Z

But the precision seems to be out slightly.

I assume its some sort of UTC with time zone?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are asking here. One has a precision of 1/1000 of a second, the other has a precision of 1/100000000. AFAIK there aren't different "types" of precision. Precision has nothing to do with time zones or UTC.

Comment: I am trying to write some Javascript code to generate (just worked it out) the 'Micro time'.

Comment: JavaScript date values only resolve to the millisecond.

Comment: If you found that on a site or API somewhere, it was likely added through a server using a scripting or programming language. Most server languages have access to microsecond precision. However, even if JS had access to microsecond time precision, some browsers restrict the precision in order to prevent it from being used to fingerprint the user.

Comment: I am doing some Java script API Integration , the Partner system expects me to return a message with a time stamp and I thought I would follow their time stamp format. I will see if toISOString() will work for now.